# How to implemet button with options list?

Tags: java, swing

I'd like to make button with options list like in Windows Start menu.

[image: Windows Start menu]

What are is simplest approach to this? (Swing question)

Comment: *"What are is simplest approach to this?"* Hire someone. BTW - Most users would prefer a `JComboBox` or a `JMenu` for this type of thing, given they are the 'path of least surprise'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `JMenu`.  The NetBeans GUI tool allows you to easily do this without the hassle of having to manually code every single detail of the menu.